# What is a Pippin at Michaelmas?

Tags: meaning, thomas-deloney, jack-of-newbury

In chapter X of Thomas Deloney's novel *Jack of Newbury*, a few characters want to take revenge on a "Mistresse Franke" (italics from the original, bold by me):

> Now certaine of the maidens of the house, and some of the yongue men, who had long before determined to bee revenged of this pratling huswife: came into the Cellar one after another, one of them bringing a great peece of a gammon of Bacon in his hand: and every one bad mistriss *Franke* welcome: and first one drunke to her, and then another, and so the third, the fourth, and the fift: so that **mistresse *Frankes* braines waxt as mellow as a Pippin at Michaelmas**, and so light, that sitting in the Cellar, she thought the world ran round.

Which [Pippin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pippin) or pippin is intended here? And what is Pippin's condition at Michaelmas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be one of those punning comparisons, that still exist in English today, but were more common in earlier centuries.

For example,

> He lies like a rug,
> It's as cold as a banker's heart.

Here, the man is lying (telling untruths) in a different way than the rug is lying (being in a horizontal position on the floor).

Looking in the OED for two possible definitions that would fit this punning comparison, we find:

> 1a.  Of fruit: ripe; soft, sweet, and juicy with ripeness.  (first citation, 1440)
> 6a. Drunk. (first citation, 1611)

A Pippin is an apple.  A Michaelmas Pippin was presumably harvested at the peak of ripeness.
So if mistresse Frankes braine was as mellow (drunk) as a Michaelmas Pippin is mellow (ripe and juicy), she must have been very drunk indeed.

For apples, it seems that *mellow* meant *ripe* but not *soft*, since apples only get soft when they are overripe. The OED has

> Thynke howe god may make of that grene apple, a swete frute full melowe. (1526   W. Bonde *Pylgrimage of Perfection*)

Today, *mellow* means mildly drunk, and good-naturedly so, but the citations in the OED seem to show that it just meant *drunk* in the 18th century and earlier. The most convincing example:

> The hateful fellow, That's crabbed when he's mellow. (1775   R. B. Sheridan *Songs Duenna*).

Comment: Is there also a pun in that last quotation? Crabs also being a type of apple and one that had more frequent culinary use then than now. Crab apples were used in making verjuice, a sour juice used in many of the ways we use vinegar or citrus juice now. So that line pulls together two apple/ripeness references.

Comment: @Spagirl: That's a clever observation. Since it's from a song about drinking, and (alcoholic) apple cider was a common drink in England back then, quite possibly.

Answer (score 1):

[Pippin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pippin) here refers to a several varieties of eating apples. Wikipedia lists several [varieties of pippin apples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pippin_apple), but all of them date from the late seventeenth to the mid-eighteenth century. The variety in Thomas Deloney's novel must be older.

[Michaelmas](https://www.historic-uk.com/CultureUK/Michaelmas/) is celebrated on 29 September. The ideal harvest time for apples varies a lot and depends both on the specific variety and the temperature, especially summer temperatures. Deloney is presumably referring to a variety that needs to be harvested early; if apples are harvest too late, they will be soft (see [Tips For Harvesting Apples And Post Harvest Apple Storing](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/apples/harvesting-and-storing-apples.htm) by Amy Grant).