# Name of this lyrical device comparing oneself to something that's described by the same word, but in another sense of the word?

Tags: song-lyrics, terminology, literary-device

Warning: The examples contain some offensive words, but I believe that is not against the rules here?

Lately I've been listening a lot to a certain hip-hop album, in which almost every track uses a certain lyrical device a lot. Instead of trying to describe it further than I already do in the title, I'll go straight to examples.

- > I've got bars for days, like a custody cell.

  [Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-intro-tyen-holding-2-lyrics) The rapper is talking about two different types of bars. First his raps, then the physical bars of a jail cell.

- > Every fucking album is banging like a Tinder-match

  [Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-smooth-operatr-lyrics) He says his albums are "banging" as in musically pleasing, but in the sense of the Tinder-match, the word means sexual intercourse.

- > I jam like a bullet stuck in the barrel

  [Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-kan-jeg-fa-et-vitne-lyrics) When he says he jams, he means musically, while the bullet is physically jammed in the barrel.

- > My woman puts on the rubber faster than a pit stop

  [Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-jura-lyrics) In the first sense he means a condom, in the second sense he means rubber tyres on a Formula 1 car.

- > I'm harder to hit than a porcupine pussy.

  [Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-per-stale-lyrics) In the first sense he means "hit" as in some sort of attack or aggressive action, in the second sense he means sexual intercourse.

- > I stay in the hood like Kenny

  [Source.](https://genius.com/Tyen-holding-per-stale-lyrics) In his own case, he means his neighbourhood, as in the slang term "hood". In the latter sense he is talking about hood as the part of a jacket that covers the head, referring to the fictional character from South Park who always wears a hood.

I think that amount of examples (there are countless more from the album, and from other rappers as well) is enough to convey what I mean.

What is the name of this lyrical device? I believe it is somewhat common in Hip Hop, and has been for decades. Does it have a name outside of Hip Hop as well, perhaps in poetry or literature?

Comment: This has been around since well before Shakespeare: *lies like a rug, [sleeps like a top](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169899/etymology-of-sleep-like-a-top), [as mellow as a Pippin at Michaelmas](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11258/what-is-a-pippin-at-michaelmas)*

Comment: @PeterShor In this example, "lie" is used both in the sense of telling falsehood, and of lying down flat on the floor? In what sens is "sleep" being used in, in terms of a top? And what other sense does mellow have?

Comment: The double meanings in these plays on words are no longer used. A top was said to be sleeping when it was spinning and yet perfectly still. And in the 16th century, *mellow* meant both  *ripe* (as a Pippin apple at Michaelmas) and *drunk*. (If you followed the links, you would get explanations.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That rhetorical device is called *zeugma*.  Merriam-Webster [defines](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeugma) zeugma as follows:

> the use of a word to modify or govern two or more words usually in such a manner that it applies to each in a different sense or makes sense with only one (as in "opened the door and her heart to the homeless boy").

[Yourdictionary.com](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-zeugma.html) provides several examples.